# Hide and show span element by clicking div element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, show-hide

I try to show and hide the Details (span element with class Details_right or Details_left) of my Resume by clicking on the specific timeline div element with the class content, but it doesn't seem to work and I do not know what I am missing.

I expected it to add and remove the class hidden to the element but it doesn't

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const content = document.querySelectorAll(".content");
  const DisplayRight = document.querySelectorAll(".Display_right");
  content.addEventListener("click", function() {
    DisplayRight.removeClass("hidden");
  });
});
```

```css
.Details_right {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 90vw;
  margin-left: -190px;
  background-color: var(--accent1-color);
  border: solid var(--background-color2) 2px;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container right">
  <div class="content">
    <h2>2022</h2>
    <p>Title</p>
  </div>
  <span class="Details_right">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes</span>
</div>
```

Comment: `querySelectorAll()` returns a static NodeList where `querySelector()`  returns the first element within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors. So, look into how you deal with the difference in the returned values between `querySelectorAll` and `querySelector`. The first error your code produces is "content.addEventListener is not a function"

Comment: There's also no element with the class "Display_right" in your markup.

Comment: Learn to use your. browser devtools inspect facility. In this case you should have seen immediately in the console that there was an error in the JS.

Comment: And there is no `removeClass` in native JS. You maybe thinking of jQuery. Try `classList.remove('hidden')`. Note: you'll have to add that class to your CSS at some point.

Comment: @j08691 this kinda triggers the event, at least i got an error message from javascript now, but it only does that for the very first Element. as i have multiple with the same class on my timeline this doesnt work :( I guess i am heading in the right direction, but more stumbling for now XD

Comment: @Boris ive never mentioned a class named display right

Comment: @AHaworth I did but just simply didnt do anything.

Comment: @Andy the class is allready there, as it also hast to be added so I dont have 10 Detail text shown all over the place :)

Comment: @Boris now I've seen it thx. also the classList.remove worked. as it wokrs now for the very first element within the timeline I guess I figure out the rest. thx for help

Comment: @HereticMonkey thanks but this isnt quite what I was looking for, but the answer below works exactly of what I thought of, so my Issue is resolved :) also i cant use the function which changes the style in a class as i am using flexbox (which you can see in my CSS snippet) it would only messes up the whole thing instantly. Also jQuery has a way more simple solution if you wanna use the Display:none version

Comment: @Yogi as I allready commented my Issue is solved. Also I cant use the Details HTML option as it doesnt fit in the rest of my Layout.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should first add the .hidden class to CSS, then use the classList.toggle in JS. Also, as contents is a list, you should use forEach and then add the event listener to every element in that list.

Modify your code as follows:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const contents = document.querySelectorAll(".content");

  contents.forEach(function(content) {
    content.addEventListener("click", function() {
      const DisplayRight = content.nextElementSibling;
      DisplayRight.classList.toggle("hidden");
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.Details_right {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 90vw;
  margin-left: -190px;
  background-color: var(--accent1-color);
  border: solid var(--background-color2) 2px;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container right">
  <div class="content">
    <h2>2022</h2>
    <p>Title</p>
  </div>
  <span class="Details_right">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes</span>
</div>
```